# How to dequeue theme's RTL stylesheet?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm developing a plugin that has its own templates to render the page. This includes header, content, footer, etc.

Therefore I have to dequeue every other style added by either theme or plugins, in order to keep the page clean. Right now I'm using this piece of code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_all_styles', 1000 );
function remove_all_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    $wp_styles->queue = array();
}
```

It almost does what I want. This dequeues every CSS file, except the theme's `rtl.css`. I'm using the default Twenty Seventeen theme.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTL stylesheet is not loaded with `wp_enqueue_style()` so it wouldn't appear in global `$wp_styles` variable. Wordpress loads it with `get_locale_stylesheet()` function. You can remove loading locale scripts completely:

```
function abort_loading_rtl_stylesheet() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'locale_stylesheet' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'abort_loading_rtl_stylesheet' );
```

or filter its output to load your custom rtl stylesheet:

```
function override_default_rtl_styles(){
    return 'path/to/custom/rtl.css';
}

add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', 'override_default_rtl_styles', 1000 );
```

I hope that's what you're looking for, cheers!